# Function of sin x

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

Give that $f(x)=\sin x$ for the domain $0\leq x \leq k$, find the greatest value of $k$ for which $f(x)$ has an inverse.

Is the answer $\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: $\sin x$ is invertible in every interval that is monotone. Apparently the question is not to find the greatest $k$ but the smallest which is $\pi/2$. Otherwise the question does not make sense to me anyway.

Comment: If $k > \pi/2$, sine isn't monotone; so, answer is $\pi/2$.

Answer (score 1):

So as f(x) to be invertible, it must be 1-1.

We will work with reductio ad absurdum. Indeed, suppose that $k > \frac{\pi}{2}$. Then, $f(x)=\sin x$ has at least two types of distinct monotony: Strictly increasing for $x\in [0, \frac{\pi}{2} ]$ and strictly decreasing immediately afterwards (but if $k> \frac{3\cdot \pi}{2}$ then monotony changes again and so on.) So, it is not 1-1 and thus, not invertible.

This means that $k\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.

But, $\sin x$ is strictly increasing $\forall x\in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$, thus the greatest k is $\frac{\pi}{2}$.